# Which CakePHP version should I download and where to place it?

Tags: php, cakephp

Can someone point me to the CakePHP version I should download?

My server is unix-based, and my directory structure is something like this:
root/home/webadmin/app_name/html/index.php

Where should I put the stuff that gets downloaded?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the manual? The installation instructions there are pretty good.

Comment: Instructions? :) No. They are usually too long-winded and I have to sift through it to get to the point I am interested in.  I don't have the patience :)

Comment: Plus my host's setup is throwing me off, so I figured I'd try to get advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download last 1.3 version (1.3.11 currently). You can download from here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/downloads. There's a 2.0 version but it's not yet finished.

Place it under `/home/webadmin/your_cake_app/`

Also, take a look at the book: http://book.cakephp.org/ Will help you.

**EDIT:**

First find your Document Root. You can do it this way:

```
<?php
$docRoot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
echo $docRoot; //Here it is
?>
```

After that, you uncompress the cakephp tgz and place it in there. If your document root is "/root/home/webadmin/app_name/html/" you place it under that html folder. The name of the folder in the tgz file must be something like "cake_###", rename it to anything related with your project. So, recap:

```
cd /root/home/webadmin/app_name/html/
wget http://[CAKE_URL AND VERSION]
tar -xzf cake.1.3.11.tar.gz
mv cake_### myProject
```

Point your server to domain/myProject and you should see the cake home page

Comment: My host has this weird /html/ directory before the place where I put files and the /app_name/ directory.  Is that common in apache setups? Its confusing me :) Currently logs get printed there.